# Magento2: How can I logout customer from controller?

Tags: magento2, customer, custom, controllers, logout

In Magento 2, I want to write a custom controller. Whenever anyone tries to call the controller

> URL (http://mymagento.com/mycontroller/index/index).

It should redirect to this controller an event dispatch should trigger to logout from Magento 2 site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try with below code.

```
        <?php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    $this->redirect = $context->getRedirect();
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function customerLogout() {
    $customerId = $this->customerSession->getId();
    if($customerId) {
        $this->customerSession->logout()
             ->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl())
             ->setLastCustomerId($customerId);
        return "logout successfully";
    } 
}
```

than push basic commands.

**I hope its work for you.**

Comment: It's showing invalid _logout() method

Comment: Never use $objectManager. It has already been deprecated. And It will make your website slow... Always define your class in **__construct** method and use it.

Comment: yes, i agree when you are working testing than its okay after than you configure in construct.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this below code in your controller file.

```
protected $session;

public function __construct(
....
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $session
....
){
....
$this->session = $session;
....
}


public function execute(){
$lastCustomerId = $this->session->getId();
$this->session->logout()->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl())->setLastCustomerId($lastCustomerId);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
$resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
$resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/logoutSuccess/');
return $resultRedirect;
}
```

**Hope it maybe helpful for you.**

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
) {
    $this->redirect = $context->getRedirect();
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}

public function customerLogout() {
    $customerId = $this->customerSession->getId();
    if($customerId) {
        $this->customerSession->logout()
             ->setBeforeAuthUrl($this->redirect->getRefererUrl())
             ->setLastCustomerId($customerId);
        return "Customer logout successfully";
    } else {
        return "Customer is not login";
    }
}
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Answer (score 2):

Use `Session destroy()` method. It's worked for me perfectly

```
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Controllername()
{
    //const MODULE_ENABLED = 'customerlogin/general/enable';
    protected $coreRegistry;
    protected $url;
    protected $resultFactory;
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $session;
    public function __construct(Registry $registry,
                                UrlInterface $url,
                                ManagerInterface $messageManager,
                                ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
                                Session $customerSession,
                                ResultFactory $resultFactory
    )
    {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

public function Yourfunction()
    {
            $this->messageManager->getMessages(true);
            // Adding a custom message
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('logout successfully.'));
            // Destroy the customer session in order to redirect him to the login page
            $this->session->destroy();
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result */
            $result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
            $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('customer/account/login'));
            return $result;
        }
```

**Note:Code Tested**

Comment: Thanks, MSA. I was looking exactly this solution. It should destroy the session of the customer and redirect to a different page.

Comment: Yes, you can change to different page @Arshad Syed

Comment: Need to change code here..              $result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('route_name/controller/action
'));

Answer (score 2):

You can simply destroy session to logout the customer.

```
/** @var Magento\Customer\Model\Session; */
$session->destroy();
```

And than redirect page to login page.

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result */
$result = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$result->setUrl($this->url->getUrl('customer/account/login'));
return $result;
```

I wish it will helps you.